# Auto update module not working after change version in odoo sh

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I change the version of my custom module I want that it should be update automatically so that my fields get upgraded because when I open my server it gave me error of field is not present. I just need to automatically update my module after pushing to odoo sh. When I change version number odoo sh gave me error:

> Test: Failed(means some test failed at that build).